# How to pass apex item value to database view?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I've a apex IR. There are few apex items to set the filter on report.

The query is so huge (more than 60K characters long) that it cannot be pasted on region source.

It also gives `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` if being called by `PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL query`.

Hence I've created a database `View` for this requirement.

But I don't how to pass these apex-item values to View.

Initially, I thought to use `apex_application_page_items` along with `apex_application_items` to fulfill the requirement. But again, I don't know how to check `session_id` or `app_user`.

Please note: Dute to a complex query and vast number of data, I can't do `select * from view where view_column = apex_item;` I need to pass apex-item into View's SQL query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass items' values *to a view*, but use them in interactive report's query.

Presume view name is `V_EMP` and it selects various values about employees. Page items are `P1_DEPT` (department) and `P1_JOB`. Query would then look like this:

```
select v.dept_name, v.emp_name, v.job, v.sal
from v_emp
where (v.dept = :P1_DEPT or :P1_DEPT is null)   --> this is where you'll
  and (v.job  = :P1_JOB  or :P1_JOB  is null)   --> use page items
order by v.dept_name, v.job, v.emp_name;
```

Comment: Due to a complex query and vast number of data, I can't do `select * from view where view_column = apex_item;` I need to pass apex-item into View's SQL query.

Comment: Depending on database version you use, that might be possible with macros (Oracle 19c and above), or SYS_CONTEXT (lower versions) (but that might, or might not work). Have a look at this AskTom discussion (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search%3Ftag%3Dhow-to-create-a-view-with-parameter)